# Get the last update time for each employee using oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried the below query to get the last update value.. But I can't get single row for each employee

```
select distinct Employee_name,Employee_status,update_time
  from Employee 
 where Employee_name= 'Muthukumar'
   and Employee_status='ACTIVE' 
 order by Employee_name, Update_time desc

Employee_name       Employee_status  Update_time
Muthukumar          ACTIVE           06-DEC-12 10.18.59.048000000 AM
Muthukumar          ACTIVE           05-DEC-12 05.05.41.165000000 AM
Muthukumar          ACTIVE           04-SEP-12 03.00.54.706000000 AM
```

Like this i will have entries for different employees. I need to get a single row for each employee with only last updated time.( Highest)

Output should be :

```
Employee_name  Employee_status   Update_time
Muthukumar     ACTIVE            06-DEC-12 10.18.59.048000000 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a classic analytic rank request. You need to rank all your rows by partitioning them by employees and order them by date. Then take only the first top rank.

Some reading [here](http://psoug.org/reference/rank.html) and [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php).

```
SELECT Employee_name, Employee_status, update_time  
FROM
(
    SELECT Employee_name, Employee_status, update_time,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_name ORDER BY update_time DESC) as Rank
    FROM Employee
)
WHERE Rank = 1
```

Comment: But where should i give the table name here?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle supports `common table expression` and `window function`. With the help of using `ROW_NUMBER()` it ranks each record of the group based on a certain order.

```
WITH empList
AS
(
    SELECT  Employee_Name,
            Employee_Status,
            Update_Time,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Employee_Name
                                ORDER BY Update_Time DESC) rn
    FROM    EmployeeList
)
SELECT  Employee_Name,
        Employee_Status,
        Update_Time
FROM    empList
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: nope, it only uses common table expression. i have a question, is the status of the user always change?

Comment: no it will not change.. just it may change in future not now.. :)